# Differential equations math help?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the equation $y' \sin x=y \ln y$. I told my teacher that we can solve if with separate variables method but he told me that we cant do that. He didn't explain why. Can you tell me why?

Comment: My guess is he just didn't want you solving it in that fashion.

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea what your teacher is at.  If by separation of variables, you mean

$$\frac{dy}{y \ln{y}} = \frac{dx}{\sin{x}}$$

Then you are on the right track here.  Integrating both sides, you get

$$\ln{\ln{y}} = \int \frac{dx}{\sin{x}} = -\ln{(\csc{x}+\cot{x})} + C$$

Comment: but the answer is lny=C *tan(x/2) :/

Comment: @sdfsd If you do some algebra and use some trig identities, they're equivalent.

Comment: Do the algebra out - it is the same thing.

Comment: ok sorry and thanks Ron. :)